# How would I successfully re-direct to my .js file (reactjs) instead of my php file upon submitting info?

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs, debugging

As of now, I'm successfully inserting information into the database (SQL, phpMyAdmin) via `Home.js` but the problem is that every time the user enters information & hits `submit`, it gets redirected to my `demo.php` file instead of `Next.js`.

In other words, how can I make it so that upon the user information successfully entering the database and go to the next page? (`Next.js`)?

I know `<form action="http://localhost/demo_react/api/demo.php" method={"POST"} encType="multipart/form-data">` will inevitably take me to `demo.php` but if I don't use this, then nothing gets submitted to my db.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Here's `Home.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Next from '../Home/Next';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: false
        };
        this.getPHP = this.getPHP.bind(this);
    }

    getPHP(e) {
        this.setState({show: true});
        let formData = new FormData();
        fetch(`http://localhost/demo_react/api/demo.php`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(response => {
                console.log('response');
                console.log(response);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
    }

    render() {
        const goNext = this.state.show;
        if(goNext) {
            return <Next/>;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <form action="http://localhost/demo_react/api/demo.php" method={"POST"} encType="multipart/form-data">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="username">Email</label>
                        <input className="form-control" type="text" name="username"/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input className="form-control" type="password" name="password"/>
                    </div>
                    <input className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login" onSubmit={e => this.getPHP(e)} name={"submit"}/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Here's `demo.php`:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "loginapp");
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) ";
    $query .= " VALUES('$username', '$password')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if (!$result) {
        die("Query failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
    } else {
        echo "check database";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a type="submit" button. Use a type="button" or a <button>. If your form didn't have a submit, the problem is solved.

Obviously, in your JS code you need to send the information. You can collect it and send to demo.php without triggering form submit. I'll show you a basic example for doing it.

```
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;
    var user = (document.getElementById(form).username) ? encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(form).username.value) : '';
    var pass = (document.getElementById(form).password) ? encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById(form).password.value) : '';
    var data = 'username=' + user + '&password=' + pass;
    request.open('POST', document.getElementById(form).action, false);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset:UTF-8");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
    request.send(data);
    if (request.status == 200) {
            alert('Send OK.');
    } else {
            alert('Send error.');
    }
```

The included snippet get the URL to send information from the form action itself. You can optimize the code a lot probably, but it's a starting point. This code uses plain JS, you can change it to jQuery for example (jQuery version its shorter for example).

Also, if you need to eventually do a redirect, use a JS redirect instead.

Comment: oh ok, I see what you mean.  I just changed it to <button>  May you please show me a working example with my code?  I've been stuck on this for so long :(

Comment: I've edited response with a example to send information from JS code.

Comment: gotcha, should I get rid of what I currently have and put this in my `getPHP()` method?

Comment: That's some based on your needs. Think if you didn't get the code inside the same function, you can reuse the code. If you need to reuse it, use multiple functions. If all is processed on the same place for same variables / form, integrate all the code in only one function.

Comment: ah ok! I see what you mean